# Check the outgoing connection from .net application

Tags: sql, .net, profiler

Is there any tool or application available to check/profile out going sql or any database requests from a .Net application? Not using SQL Profiler

Answer (score 0):

> linq pad

its's free , there is a paid version which adds autocomplete.  YOu add a reference to you dbml file from your .Net application or your Entity Context and then it uses that connection and reads your linq queries and converts them into SQL.
https://www.linqpad.net/

This is assuming that you are talking about converting LINQ or Entity queries into SQL.  Obivously if you are using basic ADO.Net Sql Queries you can just read the query straight from there , and if you are using another custom data access layer then you find to find a specific answer for that specific Data Layer.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I want something for a large .Net application.. not for some small code statements

Comment: You want something that will read everything that accesses the database? but Profiler is not an option?

Comment: What are you using as a data access layer?

Comment: Custom built tool similar to nhibernate